# Show that two groups that are isomorphic to a third group are isomorphic to each other

Tags: group-theory, self-learning, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Prove that if G is isomorphic to K and H is isomorphic to K then G and H are isomorphic to each other.

My strategy thus far has been to show that we can use composition of the respective isomorphisms to map from G to K then K to H. Would it be conclusive to show that this process can be inverted thus proving G and H are isomorphic?

Comment: Yes. Since the homorphisms from $G\to K$ and $H \to K$ are isomorphisms, they are invertible and hence so is their composition.

Answer (score 0):

Isomorphism is transitive, since the composition of two isomorphisms is an isomorphism.  This is utterly straight forward.  In fact, it's not hard to see that isomorphism defines an equivalence relation.